# How to sell my developed android application as a service to other apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase, api, package

I developed an android application, and it's working fine. In our application, we used APIs also for data collecting and updating purposes in the back end. Now my manager wants to sell the packaged API as a service to other apps. Now my point is how to do it. How to convert my project into packaged API so that other apps can use it? I developed in both android and iOS. I am new to it. Is there any way to convert my application to packaged API so that other apps can use it?

I used java for my android application and swift for iOS application, and I am using firebase as a database.

Comment: You have to create public APIs, and others can use your APIs

Comment: I don't want everyone to use my APIs. Only for our customers like those who purchased our product. @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: so make the APIs are only can be access for your client